# Does electric current actually depends upon the speed of flow of charges?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, charge

Electric current is the rate of flow of charges so can we say that it depends upon the speed of flow of charges (Is electric current directly proportional to speed of flow of charges).

If this is true then does resistors in a circuit slows down the speed of flow of charges and hence decreases the electric current of the circuit.

If the speed of flow of charges is increased then what will be its impact on the resistance of the resistor

Comment: This comes up time and time again. Here's just one example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563535/confusion-regarding-current-and-resistance-in-series-circuit?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion regarding current and resistance in series circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563535/confusion-regarding-current-and-resistance-in-series-circuit)

Comment: TLDR: Current is proportional to the number of units of charge that pass a given point in a unit of time. Specifically, one [Ampere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere) of current is one [Coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb) of charge per second. The speed with which the individual charged particles move is not part of that definition.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Answer (score 1):

As a simple model of current flow in a conductor consider a wire of constant cross sectional area $A$,then suppose that there are $ n $ charge carriers per unit volume each carrying charge $ q $ and moving in the same direction with speed $ v $, The number of charges that pass through the circular cross section in a time $ \Delta t $ is $$ n A v \Delta t. $$
[image]
As each carrier carries a charge $ q $then the total amount of charge that has passed through is $$ \Delta Q = q n A v \Delta t $$ and the rate at which charge passing through is $$ \frac{ \Delta Q}{ \Delta t } = n q A v,$$ which is just how the current $ I $ is defined.

So the current depends upon the speed but also on the number of charge carriers.

Answer (score 0):

> Electric current is the rate of flow of charges

Correct. It's charge per time.

> so can we say that it depends upon the speed of flow of charges

Not really. It's the other way around. Current is flowing which causes electrons to move. How fast they move depends a lot on the material properties and geometry of the conductor. For the same current, electrons can go  fast or slow depending on what it is they are going through.

> Is electric current directly proportional to speed of flow of charges

Yes and no. The drift speed electrons in a conductor (or resistor) is indeed proportional to the current. But the proportionality factor depends on the properties and the geometry of the conductor. The drift speed can vary inside a conductor if the conductor isn't uniform.

So it is proportional but the proportionality is different from wire to wire or resistor to resistor

> If this is true then does resistors in a circuit slows down the speed of flow of charges and hence decreases the electric current of the circuit.

Not really. The speed of the electrons is different in each part of the circuit (resistors, wires, etc). What is constant is the current, which is the number of charges per time.

> If the speed of flow of charges is increased then what will be its impact on the resistance of the resistor

None whatsoever. The resistance is a property of the material and the geometry. It doesn't change with current or voltage (at least not as primary effect).

Answer (score 0):

In classical theory, the current is proportional to the density of free electrons and the average drift velocity (which results from the free electrons being accelerated by an electric field between collisions with the atoms of the conductor).  In achieving a steady flow, the density of free electrons adjusts itself (and the field) so the total flow across any given cross-section of the circuit is constant.